# By default how are missing data dealt with in lmer (lme4)?

Tags: r, missing-data, random-effects-model, lme4-nlme

Running a linear mixed effects model in R (lme4) using "lmer" function. Missing values are coded as "NA". Missing values are from the DV and some predictor variables also. By default how are these missing data treated when I run the model?

Comment: Relevant entries are dropped.

Comment: You can check things like this by referring to documentation.

Comment: I think it is on-topic, especially if it is worded more generally than just focusing on the lme4 package. For instance, I know that the lmer() function (and multilevel modeling more generally) can handle missing observations. However, I do not know the *statistics* behind this; I would like to hear a conceptual/statistical explanation of it, and that's how I interpreted the question.